# How do you add a lib namespace to Wordpress roots sage?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Following the documentation written [here](https://roots.io/upping-php-requirements-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/), I added a file to lib directory containing:

```
<?php

namespace Theme\URIs;

/**
 * Returns theme images directory uri
 */
function get_images_directory_uri() {
    return get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images';
}
```

Which I then tried calling from a template file with:

```
<?php print Theme\URIs\get_images_directory_uri(); ?>
```

Calling this however, returned a `Fatal error: Call to undefined function Theme\URIs\get_images_directory_uri()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the file to the `$sage_includes` array in `functions.php`, so it looks like this:

```
$sage_includes = [
  'lib/assets.php',  // Scripts and stylesheets
  'lib/extras.php',  // Custom functions
  'lib/setup.php',   // Theme setup
  'lib/titles.php',  // Page titles
  'lib/wrapper.php',  // Theme wrapper class
  'lib/uris.php' // Project URIs
];
```

This imports the file to be used in the theme.

The present documentation does not explain this. (I assumed it simply imported all files in the libs directory...)

Answer (score 0):

Not the question (I can't comment yet) but unless you've changed the directory structure your function should probably return:

```
get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/images';
```

As the images in `/assets/images` get optimised and then copied to `/dist/images`.